# How can I set the same background-image for every page with a button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails

I have several buttons, each of them changes a background. But the problem is that it is not depicted on every page and I have to reset a background clicking these buttons all the time. 
**Application.html.erb**

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground('paper')" color="black">Black</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeBackground"('gray')">Gray</button>

<script>

function myFunction(color) {
        if (color == "paper"){
         $('body').css('background-image', 'some image')
        }
        if (color == "gray"){
         $('body').css('background-image', 'some image')
     }
   }
</script>
```

These backgrounds are working on one page only. How can I set a background once for every page? Thank you!

Comment: Aside from the typos, there's no reason this wouldn't work on any page. Have you included the script correctly on those pages? Checked the console for errors?

Comment: store the background image url as a cookie so it can be read on multiple html pages withing your website -- https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is let the user set different visual themes on the page you can use a cookie together with a class attribute.

```
module ThemingHelper
  def theme_class
    classes = []
    # lets check if the cookie is acceptable first:
    if ["theme-1", "theme-2"].include?(cookies[:theme])
      classes << cookies[:theme]
    end
    classes.join(" ").html_safe
  end
end
```

layouts.html.erb:

```
# ...
<body class="<%= theme_class %>">
# ...
```

application.css:

```
body.theme-1 {
  background-color: 'red';
}

body.theme-2 {
  background-color: 'blue';
}
```

Now lets setup the javascript to handle changing themes:

```
<button class="change-theme" data-theme="theme-1">Classic</button>
<button class="change-theme" data-theme="theme-2">Funky fresh</button>
```

Notice that we don't use inline handlers. Its a bad practice that is easily avoided with jQuery.

```
$(document).on('click', '.change-theme', function(){
  var theme = $(this).data('theme');
  document.cookie = "theme=" + theme;
  $(body).removeClass("theme-1 theme-2").addClass(theme);
  return false;
});
```

This might seem convoluted but is actually the right way to do it:

- HTML is just content
- Stylesheets handle presentation
- Javascript enhances behavior

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie